# Algorithm2e, [italianokw] does not function. Why?

Tags: algorithm2e

In my code below, the option [italianokw] of `algorithm2e`--package does not function. Why? (I am new in use of this package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italianokw,linesnumbered,lined,boxruled,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\SetAlFnt{\Large}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Somma unaria}\label{alg:Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{int piu(int $n$, int $m$)}{return $m+n$.\;}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{piu($m,n$)}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$\\\textbf{return} $m$.}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

**First Edit:** More precisely, I'd like to have in the caption (with larger font possibly) **Algoritmo 1.** Somma unaria.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `italiano` option to change everything and not only the keywords. This will adapt the name of the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italiano,linesnumbered,lined,boxruled,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\def\AlCapFnt{\Large}
\def\AlCapNameFnt{\Large}
\SetAlFnt{\Large}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Somma unaria}\label{alg:Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{int piu(int $n$, int $m$)}{return $m+n$.\;}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{piu($m,n$)}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$\\\textbf{return} $m$.}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `babel`, I suggest to use its features instead of the (not well-implemented) `italiano` option.

I also suggest some changes in how to typeset math and avoid those horrible slanted parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[
  twocolumn,% <--- just to make a smaller picture
  a4paper,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  left=1.5cm,
  right=1.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
italiano,
  italianokw,
  linesnumbered,
  lined,
  boxruled,
  commentsnumbered
]{algorithm2e}

\setlocalecaption{italian}{listalgorithmcf}{Elenco degli Algoritmi}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{algorithmcf}{Algoritmo}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{algorithmcfline}{riga}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{@algocf@proc}{Procedura}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{@algocf@func}{funzione}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vartype}{m}{\ifmmode\mathrm{#1}\ \else\textup{#1}\fi}

%\SetAlFnt{\Large} % <---- No, please!

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Somma unaria}\label{alg:Somma unaria}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Funzione}{}{}
\Fn{\vartype{int} $\mathit{piu}(\vartype{int} n, \vartype{int} m)$}{return $m+n$.\;}
\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{}
\Def{$\mathit{piu}(m,n)$}{\While{$n!=0$}{$m,n=m+1,n-1$\\\textbf{return} $m$.}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I dislike twocolumn-option of geometry. Please could you answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697886/algorithm-in-box-and-settings)? Thx

Comment: @Puck Here it's used just in order to get a smaller picture, it suggests nothing for the other problem that I think is not solvable with `algorithm2e`.